# what are the parameter need to check out before shutting down the switch port?

Tags: lan, switching, layer2, port-security

If a switch is running in the live network and a port of it was in use before now.so I wants to shut it down. what are the parameter / things I need to check ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please edit it with more detail. Do you mean what are the commands to shut it down (varies by vendor), or are you really asking if there is something like checking to see if it is still in use (again, varies by vendor)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to shutdown this port just for security purpose may you need to check the next.

1. if any user plugged in
2. if any switch plugged in
3. if it is working as a plan B for any physical failure
4. check the running configuration if it is part of any policy , NAT (if you run on cisco appliance may you issue #sh run | inc )
5. if it is attached to any VLAN may you need to know what is the use of this vlan

that is not all but it will keep you in safe side .

Answer (score 0):

Copy or backup existing interface configuration.